# Showing different button image on touch

Tags: ios, uibutton

For what I would have thought would have been a simple questions I am not able to find a solution anywhere so any help would be greatly appreciated.

My plan was to create a custom button with a image and when you click the image it shows another image until the image is clicked again, where it would revert back to the original image.

So there would be two images, a click would show image 1, a second click would show image 2 a third click would show image 1 again and so on a bit like a switch.

I have tried a load of ideas that I have found online but none of them work.

Anyone out there that could help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rather than me writing all your code for you, why don't you post some of your efforts and I can point out the few things you need to change to get them to work...?

Comment: Hi rmaddy, sorry I don't see how they are the same questions, this one is like a switch so show two different images, so on would be one image, off would be another image. The other question I asked was how would I run a different animations on a button with different clicks, maybe 3 or 4 different animations so click 1 would run animation 1, click 2 would run animation 2, click 3 would run animation 3. How is that the same question? Thanks for your input in explaining to me this if that is the case as I am new to Xcode and i don't see them as the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set different images for default state and selected state.

```
UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setImage:@"image1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:@"image2" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then toggle the state when the button is clicked

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
     button.selected = !button.selected;
     //...
}
```

Comment: Hi Taha, where would I set the first section of this code? would i create a void for the button or would it go in the view did load?

Comment: it can go in the view did load